# Does laser-induced graphene (LIG) stay functional after being extracted from the substrate?

Tags: materials-engineering, graphene

So, I've seen some videos about laser induced graphene and its use as either a supercapacitor or as a low-voltage heater.

In [this video](https://youtu.be/RKcUgdXUf9Y?t=554) the person only uses two electrodes on each end of the LIG tape to make such low-voltage heater. But one of the remarks he makes is that the heater will only work until the kapton tape fails due to its temperature.

So I was wondering if extracting the LIG from the Kapton tape, the graphene would still work. But I don't know how such thing would be achieved.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but did you find the answer over the last 6+ months? If so please let us know! Otherwise, are you still actively needing an answer?

Comment: @NikeDattani I didn't find it, but I asked other places and looked on some articles about the subject, and I *think* it does.

Comment: Are you still actively needing an answer?

Comment: @NikeDattani nope, but if you have one, I would be glad tho :)